# SSRS report not having the same font formatting on PREVIEW and PRINT

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Had this issue when working with report viewer - now having the same issue with SSRS. Basically what happens is I create a report with a certain font - it looks perfect in the preview mode - however, when I go to print it - it makes the text look different - kind of squeezed and looks to be complete different font as a matter of fact. Included image with what it looks like in PREVIEW and PRINT.[image]

Anyone had an issue like this before?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/rendering-behaviors-report-builder-and-ssrs) and many similar ones give information about rendering, but none of them seem to answer the questions "does this text fit in this box?" and "How big will this box be?" Rendering to IE, Chrome, Safari, Word, and PDF was an exercise in frustration and compromise, especially considering that Visual Studio and Report Builder were also different. In all cases, the height and width of the text boxes changed, the font size changed, and the spacing around the text changed.

Our technique was to prioritize the various output formats, then find settings that produced the best output based on those priorities. Given this, users see better (but still not quite perfect) results than we see in Visual Studio.